# Can we use reverse image search to bypass image CAPTCHAs?

Tags: captcha

Has there been any group that managed to bypass the Image CAPTCHAs using reverse image search? Whats stopping people from writing a script that bypasses these CAPTCHAs by reverse image searching via many services like Google and make a choice?

And also can this be done? I can imagine writing a python script that cuts one of the nine images in the captcha and then reverse searches it using a website, but the real challenge is how to make sense of the results and come to conclusion that whether this is for example a store front or not? Any ideas?

has there been any open source project demonstrating this? i want to write a python script that demonstrates this for a college project but its really hard, specially deciding based on the results that whether a picture is correct or not, since some results might be really complex. for example when they say locate pictures with sidewalks in them and the picture has many other stuff in it, it gets really hard to make sense of the results.

Comment: *"...and can anyone provide me useful web services that do reverse image search other than google?..."  - this part of your question is off-topic.

Comment: Also - a simple search for [captcha reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=captcha+reverse+image+search) gives me [I’m not a human: Breaking the Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf) from Blackhat Asia 2016 as first hit - and this looks like it will answer your question.

Comment: this is one of the AI applications on image recognition - here is a recent related article to hopefully help your with your investigation: http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/news/new-attack-could-make-website-security-captchas-obsolete

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but has there been any open source project that demonstrates it? because the real challenge is to make a decision based on the reverse results, also how do big websites like twitter and facebook prevent this from happening? or do they?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be bypassed and it was by quite a lot of groups/people. There are several payed services that offer exactly that. Their methods are advanced enough to recognize the images and solve it successfully, even better than most humans when it comes to text and with above 50% success rate when it comes to pictures, which is more than sufficient to bypass it.

To understand some of the ways this is possible, read the paper [I’m not a human: Breaking the Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf)